# Spring MongoRepository filter string date column

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, filter, mongorepository

Is it possible to filter a MongoRepository in Spring where there is a column with date strings like that:

```
2019-01-01T00:00:00
2022-01-20T00:00:00
2022-05-01T00:00:00
```

I try to get all columns where the Date value is after a certain date.

I tried the following statements:

```
findAllByPersonIdAndDateAfter(int id, Date after);

findAllByDateAfter(Date date)

findAllByDateGreaterThan(Date date);
```

Invoked it with e.g.:

```
Date after = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2022-03-31 23:00:00");
repository.findAllByDateAfter(after)
```

But it always returns 0 rows.

Comment: Are the dates persisted in MongoDB using `string` or `date` type?

Comment: They are persisted as string..